# NSIS custom page to choose for installing an add-on or not

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm still a noob with NSIS. How can I write a custom page in the installer with something to let the user choose whether he wants to install an add-on or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not already using the components page you could just use that: `Section /o "Foo component"`

To create a custom page you have to use [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) or [InstallOptions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/InstallOptions/Readme.html)...